# R Shiny app - "Disconnected from the server. Reload."

Tags: r, shiny

I am attempting to update what had been a fully functioning R Shiny App with a feature that allows users to select locations from a map for plotting results (users previously had to select locations from a long list of names).  I was following this helpful example, https://uasnap.shinyapps.io/ex_leaflet/.

Everything works great locally, but not when I publish it to shinyapps.io, https://jvadams.shinyapps.io/StreamShot/.  I get the message `Disconnected from the server.  Reload.`  If I right click in the window (I'm using Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110) and select `Inspect` and look at the console tab, I see the warning message `[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.`  **Any advice on how to fix this issue?**

I get the same `Disconnected from the server.  Reload.` message when I try to open the App in Internet Explorer (Version 11.0.9600.18697).  But, when I right click, `Inspect`, and look at the console tab there, I have no errors or warnings.

I did a little searching on-line.  I found a suggestion to change the `selectize` argument in `selectInput` to `FALSE` (it's set to `TRUE` by default), but that didn't fix things.  I found some other posts, but they don't make sense to me ... things about ajax and jquery which I don't understand.

I prepared a much simplified example app to reproduce the problem for posting here, but the simplified app works without any problem, https://jvadams.shinyapps.io/Testing/.  I guess this isn't surprising, since the example I'm working from was also posted on shinyapps.io and it seems to work fine.

What's the difference between the real thing and the simplified example?  The real thing has 3 more data frames, each data frame has many more records (maximum number of rows ~ 30,000), there are more plots (10-15 plots per tabbed page using `tabsetPanel()` and `tabPanel()`), and there are some data tables, too.  The real thing also has a few `plotly` plots.  But all of these plots and tables in the real thing rely on the single choice of location made from the map or the list, just as in the simple example.

Might my connection speed be a problem?  I use my cellphone's 4G hotspot for an internet connection (31 Mbps according to https://fast.com/).

I'm using R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21), RStudio Version 1.0.143, on a PC with Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4600m CPU, 2.90 GHz processor, 16.0 GB RAM, and Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise operating system 2009 Service Pack 1.

The Rmarkdown (*.Rmd) code for the simple example is shown in full below:

````
---
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE, echo=FALSE} 
knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE)
```

```{r}
# non reactive stuff
library(leaflet)
library(rbokeh)
library(tidyverse)

locs <- structure(list(loc = c("S-US-611: BAD RIVER", "H-US-216: TROUT RIVER", 
  "M-US-67: GIERKE CREEK", "H-US-71: TROUT CREEK", "S-US-13: PENDILLS CREEK", 
  "O-US-67: RICE CR.", "M-US-271: EPHRAIM CREEK", "M-US-674: GIBSON CREEK (HALFWAY CREEK)", 
  "S-US-64: SUCKER RIVER", "M-US-339: EAST TWIN RIVER"), lon = c(-90.652399, 
  -83.826602, -86.336641, -84.103548, -84.819236, -76.56845, -87.179319, 
  -86.206658, -85.942378, -87.563722), lat = c(46.637999, 45.428862, 
  45.849507, 45.979098, 46.443969, 43.443795, 45.148478, 42.719827, 
  46.674155, 44.151644), le = c(1.10611, 3.10216, 2.10067, 3.10071, 
  1.10013, 5.10067, 2.10271, 2.10674, 1.10064, 2.10339)), .Names = c("loc", 
  "lon", "lat", "le"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
row.names(locs) <- locs$loc

chem <- structure(list(le = c(1.00093, 1.00093, 1.00093, 1.00093, 1.00093, 
  1.00093, 1.00093, 1.00093, 1.00093, 1.00116, 1.00116, 1.00116, 
  1.00116, 1.00116, 1.00301, 1.00301, 1.00301, 1.00301, 1.00301, 
  1.00301, 1.00301, 1.00374, 1.00374, 1.00374, 1.00374, 1.00374, 
  1.00374, 1.00374, 1.00374, 1.00374, 1.00374, 1.00374, 1.00374, 
  1.00374, 1.10013, 1.10013, 1.10013, 1.10013, 1.10013, 1.10013, 
  1.10015, 1.10064, 1.10064, 1.10064, 1.10064, 1.10064, 1.10064, 
  1.10064, 1.10064, 1.10064, 1.10064, 1.10064, 1.10064, 1.10064, 
  1.10064, 1.10064, 1.10064, 1.10064, 1.10064, 1.10064, 1.10064, 
  1.10064, 1.10064, 1.10064, 1.10064, 1.10064, 1.10064, 1.10064, 
  1.10064, 1.10064, 1.10064, 1.10064, 1.10611, 1.10611, 1.10611, 
  1.10611, 1.10611, 1.10611, 1.10611, 1.10611, 1.10611, 1.10611, 
  1.10611, 1.10611, 1.10611, 1.10611, 1.10611, 1.10611, 1.10611, 
  1.10611, 1.10611, 1.10611, 1.10611, 2.10271, 2.10339, 2.10339, 
  2.10339, 2.10339, 2.10339, 2.10339, 2.10339, 2.10339, 2.10523, 
  2.10523, 2.10523, 2.10523, 2.10523, 2.10523, 2.10523, 2.10523, 
  2.10523, 2.10523, 2.10523, 2.10523, 2.10523, 2.10674, 2.10674, 
  3.10071, 3.10071, 3.10071, 3.10071, 3.10071, 3.10071, 3.10071, 
  3.10071, 3.10071, 3.10071, 3.10071, 3.10071, 3.10202, 3.10202, 
  3.10202, 3.10202, 3.10202, 3.10202, 3.10202, 3.10202, 3.10202, 
  3.10202, 3.10202, 3.10202, 3.10202, 3.10202, 3.10202, 3.10202, 
  3.10202, 3.10202, 3.10202, 3.10202, 3.10202, 3.10216, 3.10216, 
  3.10216, 3.10216, 3.10216, 3.10216, 3.10216, 3.10216, 3.10216, 
  3.10216, 3.10216, 3.10216, 3.10216, 3.10216, 3.10216, 3.10296, 
  3.10296, 3.10296, 3.10296, 3.10296, 3.10296, 3.10296, 3.10296, 
  3.10296, 3.10296, 3.10296, 3.10296, 3.10296, 3.10296, 3.10296, 
  5.10067, 5.10071, 5.10071, 5.10071, 5.10071, 5.10071, 5.10071, 
  5.10071, 5.10071, 5.10071, 5.10071), year = c(1962L, 1966L, 1971L, 
  1975L, 1984L, 1997L, 2001L, 2008L, 2012L, 1991L, 1995L, 1999L, 
  2004L, 2009L, 1963L, 1966L, 1971L, 1978L, 1988L, 2005L, 2012L, 
  1963L, 1967L, 1971L, 1975L, 1978L, 1982L, 1986L, 1990L, 1994L, 
  1999L, 2003L, 2007L, 2009L, 1959L, 1963L, 1973L, 1982L, 1988L, 
  2012L, 2012L, 1958L, 1959L, 1961L, 1963L, 1965L, 1967L, 1969L, 
  1971L, 1972L, 1973L, 1974L, 1975L, 1977L, 1979L, 1980L, 1981L, 
  1982L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1989L, 1990L, 1992L, 
  1994L, 1996L, 1998L, 2002L, 2006L, 2010L, 1960L, 1963L, 1964L, 
  1968L, 1969L, 1971L, 1973L, 1977L, 1978L, 1980L, 1984L, 1988L, 
  1991L, 1995L, 1998L, 2001L, 2003L, 2005L, 2007L, 2008L, 2011L, 
  1963L, 1975L, 1979L, 1982L, 1987L, 1995L, 2000L, 2004L, 2008L, 
  1963L, 1967L, 1971L, 1974L, 1978L, 1983L, 1987L, 1991L, 1995L, 
  1999L, 2002L, 2006L, 2010L, 1965L, 1984L, 1966L, 1970L, 1972L, 
  1973L, 1975L, 1979L, 1984L, 1989L, 1994L, 2001L, 2005L, 2009L, 
  1968L, 1972L, 1974L, 1976L, 1977L, 1979L, 1980L, 1982L, 1984L, 
  1985L, 1986L, 1988L, 1991L, 1993L, 1994L, 1997L, 1998L, 2002L, 
  2008L, 2009L, 2012L, 1967L, 1970L, 1974L, 1978L, 1982L, 1985L, 
  1989L, 1993L, 1997L, 2000L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2011L, 
  1969L, 1972L, 1975L, 1979L, 1980L, 1983L, 1985L, 1989L, 1993L, 
  1997L, 2000L, 2002L, 2006L, 2008L, 2011L, 1972L, 1978L, 1982L, 
  1985L, 1988L, 1991L, 1995L, 1998L, 2002L, 2005L, 2011L), alk.mgl = c(33, 
  27, 20, 26, 14, 27, 51, 28, 26, 19, 20, 22, 27, 20, 78, 78, 68, 
  73, 71, 83, 73, 27, 19, 27, 18, 15, 12, 13, 15, 12, 30, 17, 12, 
  37, 38, 34, 34, 30, 36, 40, 62, 60, 68, 48, 66, 65, 56, 68, 48, 
  46, 50, 60, 70, 54, 56, 54, 76, 50, 24, 68, 62, 70, 80, 67, 71, 
  70, 62, 60, 61, 70, 77, 45, 46, 20, 56, 91, 50, 52, 46, 82, 54, 
  58, 82, 96, 86, 86, 99, 84, 86, 96, 67, 86, 99, 200, 175, 266, 
  256, 288, 280, 250, 202, 264, 142, 158, 150, 165, 182, 162, 148, 
  160, 158, 155, 150, 170, 160, 84, 68, 95, 58, 80, 116, 55, 55, 
  58, 36, 62, 60, 93, 80, 149, 159, 165, 164, 176, 150, 168, 154, 
  154, 166, 140, 148, 170, 160, 160, 155, 155, 163, 175, 155, 165, 
  145, 170, 190, 200, 164, 188, 188, 170, 130, 170, 160, 140, 150, 
  200, 170, 174, 182, 180, 197, 144, 154, 175, 180, 180, 178, 180, 
  180, 185, 185, 180, 70, 104, 137, 113, 133, 123, 147, 117, 101, 
  146, 125)), .Names = c("le", "year", "alk.mgl"), row.names = c(NA, 
  -191L), class = "data.frame")
```

```{r}
# reactive stuff
theworks <- reactive({
  i <- input$location
  pick <- locs$loc == i
  j <- locs$le[pick]

  # map data
  infosub <- locs[pick, ]

  # chemistry data
  CHEMsub <- chem[chem$le==j, ]

  list(infosub=infosub, CHEMsub=CHEMsub)
})
```

```{r}
# server
acm_defaults <- function(map, x, y) {
  addCircleMarkers(map, x, y, radius=6, color="black", 
    fillColor="orange", fillOpacity=1, opacity=1, weight=2, stroke=TRUE, 
    layerId="Selected")
}

# map
output$Map <- renderLeaflet({
  leaflet() %>% 
    # Great Lakes centered
    setView(lng=-84, lat=45, zoom=6) %>% 
    addTiles() %>%
    addCircleMarkers(data=locs, radius=6, color="black", label=~loc,
      stroke=FALSE, fillOpacity=0.5, group="locations", layerId=~loc)
})

# update the map markers and view on map clicks
observeEvent(input$Map_marker_click, { 
  p <- input$Map_marker_click
  proxy <- leafletProxy("Map")
  if(p$id=="Selected"){
    proxy %>% 
      removeMarker(layerId="Selected")
  } else {
    proxy %>% 
      setView(lng=p$lng, lat=p$lat, input$Map_zoom) %>% 
      acm_defaults(p$lng, p$lat)
  }
})

# update the location selectInput on map clicks
observeEvent(input$Map_marker_click, { 
  p <- input$Map_marker_click
  if(!is.null(p$id)) {
    if(is.null(input$location) || input$location!=p$id) {
      updateSelectInput(session, "location", selected=p$id)
    }
  }
})

# update the map markers and view on location selectInput changes
observeEvent(input$location, { 
  p <- input$Map_marker_click
  p2 <- subset(locs, loc==input$location)
  proxy <- leafletProxy("Map")
  if(nrow(p2)==0) {
    proxy %>% 
      removeMarker(layerId="Selected")
  } else { 
    if(length(p$id) && input$location!=p$id) {
      proxy %>% 
        setView(lng=p2$lon, lat=p2$lat, input$Map_zoom) %>% 
        acm_defaults(p2$lon, p2$lat)
    } else { 
      if(!length(p$id)) {
        proxy %>% 
          setView(lng=p2$lon, lat=p2$lat, input$Map_zoom) %>% 
          acm_defaults(p2$lon, p2$lat)
      } 
    }
  }
})

output$alk <- renderRbokeh({
  df <- theworks()$CHEMsub
  if(dim(df)[1] > 0) {
    figure() %>%
      ly_points(df$year, df$alk.mgl)
  } else {
    return()
  }
})
```

```{r}
# ui
fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
      h4(strong("Select stream from list or map")),
      selectInput("location", "", c("", locs$loc), selected=""),
      br(), 
      h4("Alkalinity"),
      rbokehOutput("alk")
    ),
    column(7,
      p("(Hover to see identities of other streams.)"),
      leafletOutput("Map", width="510px", height="510px")
    )
  )
)
```
````

Answer (score 3):

One of the libraries I had been loading for the real app was from Github. When I used a workaround to avoid loading that package, the app worked both locally and on shinyapps.io.